# How to create custom action space in openai.gym

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to upgrade code for custom environment written in gym==0.18.0 to latest version of gym. My current action space and observation space are defined as

self.observation_space = np.ndarray(shape=(24,))
self.action_space = [0, 1]

I understand that in the new version the spaces have to be inherited from gym.spaces class. Can someone help me on how to rewrite my spaces (observation/action) to implement the gym.spaces?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of a 1D observation space, it could be something like:

```
self.observation_shape = (24, 1, 3)

self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low = np.zeros(self.observation_shape),  high = np.ones(self.observation_shape),dtype = np.float16)

self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3,)
```

See also: https://blog.paperspace.com/creating-custom-environments-openai-gym/

Comment: Thank you. this resolved my issue. For those of you looking for exact answer it is 
''''
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np
import random
space = spaces.Discrete(2,)

print(space.sample())
''''